# Two-dimensional array of character arrays PROGMEM Arduino

Tags: pointers, multidimensional-array, arduino

My first approach to solving my problem was to try to make a dictionary/hash table, but I was told that was a bad idea. I was sent to *[PROGMEM](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM)*. Now my problem right now is that I am making a menu system using a touchscreen. I need each of the buttons to be available in different languages, so there is a memory location that stores the current language, 0 - English, 1 - Spanish, 2 - French. When I turn on the system, it reads this value into a char/byte variable called `lang`.

I want my code to work like this (where LANG_SOUND is a constant value 7):

```
const char* dictionary[3][8] PROGMEM = {
    {"Account", "Date and Time", "Idle", "Language", "Main Menu", "Prescription", "Settings", "Sound"},
    {"Cuenta", "Fecha y Hora", "Espera", "Idioma", "Menú Principal", "Receta", "Configuración", "Sonido"},
    {"Compte", "Date et heure", "Idle", "Langue", "Main Menu", "prescription", "Paramètres", "Son"}
};

strcpy_P(buffer, (char*) pgm_read_word (&(dictionary[lang][LANG_SOUND])));  
screen.print(buffer, CENTER, 23);
```

The *PROGMEM* page I mentioned above creates the dictionary a little differently. My problem right now is that the code above is not working. It may be that the 8 is not for 8 string elements but as 8 maximum characters per string, I'm unsure if I've screwed up my pointers a little.

So, what is the problem above, and how do I fix it? Moreover, must I create the dictionary/string_table the way shown in the link, or can I do it as I have done it above? (The way I have done it above seems easier for me since I will end up having about 40 menu screens and tons of text.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You don't HAVE TO use `PROGMEM

Well, you really don't use `PROGMEM`. If you want to avoid that hassle now, just drop the `PROGMEM` attribute from `dictionary` and use something like:

```
screen.print(dictionary[lang][LANG_SOUND], CENTER, 23);
```

However, if you have a lot of data like this, you might need to use `PROGMEM`. But if you want to get the other parts of your app developed now, just omit forget the `PROGMEM` part for now.

#### Using `PROGMEM`

Unfortunately, you do have to use `PROGMEM` almost exactly as it is in that example, i.e. declaring a unique variable for each `PROGMEM` string. You don't have to store the table in `PROGMEM` though.  But lines like this:

```
prog_char dictEnglishSalami[] PROGMEM = "Salami";
prog_char dictEnglishProsecco[] PROGMEM = "Prosecco";
```

will be required.  The `dictionary` table which will look like

```
const char *string_table[] = {
   dictEnglishSalami,
   dictEnglishProsecco,
   ...
   };
```

can be declared `PROGMEM` or not, but why not at this point?

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly! When I'm done with the project I'll just write a program that will convert the table to PROGMEM using the approach you mentioned!

Comment: Cool! Depending on how much memory space you are using for your string table, you might have to do it much sooner.  Keep an eye on available free memory, once you get down to under 10% Arduinos/AVRs start behaving erratically.  If you get weird behavior, that's the first thing to check.